# automatically log in to windows security form using vb dotnet

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to build an application using VB .Net that will automatically log into ADP so that I can automatically download a time card report.  I tried to show an image, but because I am new I am unable.  You can view the form by going to https://portal.adp.com/public/index.htm and clicking User Login.  Can someone tell me how to populate the User name and Password text boxes?  I have spent a lot of time searching, but haven't been unable to find any information on this.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to interact with the site, you can simply use the [`Credentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx) property because this is a standard HTTP-login.

```
Dim client As New WebClient()
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password")
Dim pageData As String = client.DownloadString("https://portal.adp.com/wps/employee/employee.jsp")
```

Here more information about the [`NetworkCredential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential_members%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class. Also you can take a look at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvcs/thread/95070e0a-5972-4b27-bbf0-0d5f3795f28c). If you are using a `WebBrowser` control, you can use [this method](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/220962/Webbrowser-with-Credentials).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Internet Explorer add-in, and use that to fill in the form and login. Here is a tutorial I found.

http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/07/09/create-addons-ie10/